# Two othrogonal vectors multiplication properties.

Tags: vectors

Suppose we have 2 orthogonal vectors, $D$ and $V$, which are defined as follows:

$D = 2x-y$

$V = 2x+y$

The question is what can we deduce about the $||x||$ and $||y||$?

Now I tried the following, but I am not sure this is correct; so I'd like a verification of my solution. Since we know that $D$ and $V$ are orthogonal vectors then their dot product would be equal to zero; so we can say the following:

$D \cdot V = 0 \rightarrow (2x-y) \cdot (2x+y) = 0 \rightarrow 4x^2+2xy-2xy-y^2 = 0 \rightarrow$

$  4x^2 - y^2 = 0 \rightarrow 4x^2 = y^2$

So  $2||x|| = ||y||$.

Comment: In what vector space, with what inner product (or bilinear form), over what field...?!

Comment: I think it doesn't matter, provided you're using the norm defined by the inner product...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks almost right, except that you need to make the distinction between vectors and scalars: 
$ (2x - y) \dot \ (2x + y) = (2x) \dot\  (2x) - y \dot\ (2x) + (2x) \dot\ y - y \dot\ y $ - which given an equation about their moduli since $x \dot\ x = \lvert x \rvert ^2$.

(Your reasoning is actually fine, you've just switched in places between refering to $x$ the vector and $x = \lvert x \rvert$ the scalar).

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the verification ;).